# Call RSS Feed in VBA and Scrape Certain Data

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am writing a script in VBA within PowerPoint. I am trying to grab the following line from an [RSS Feed](https://water.weather.gov/ahps2/rss/fcst/fdyo1.rss): `&#x3C;div&#x3E;Highest Projected Forecast Available: 1.2 ft&#x3C;/div&#x3E;`

From that line I need to extract just the "1.2" or whatever value appears in that place. The problem I am coming across is that it is not formatted like a standard XML file. It does not have tags at the beginning of each line, instead they are character combinations like you see in the example line above. Is this normal for an RSS feed? Click the link above to see exactly what I am referring to.

Any ideas how I would be able to grab that value and store it as a variable with VBA in PowerPoint? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Please check the following code hope that helps:

```
Function GetRSSResults() As String
GetRSSResults = GetHTTPResponse("https://water.weather.gov/ahps2/rss/fcst/fdyo1.rss")
r = GetRSSResults
s1 = Replace(r, "&#x3E;", ">")
s2 = Replace(s1, "&#x3C;", "<")
searchTerm = "Highest Projected Forecast Available: "
s = InStr(s2, searchTerm) + Len(searchTerm)
l = InStr(s, s2, "ft")
Debug.Print Trim(Mid(s2, s, l - s))
End Function
'------------------------------------------
Function GetHTTPResponse(url As String) As String
Dim msXML As Object
Set msXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
With msXML
  .Open "Get", url, False
  .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
  .send
  GetHTTPResponse = .responseText
End With
Set msXML = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ran your script, but it returns 2 blank lines. I do not get any errors or anything when it is run. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: The output will show up in Immediate window and I am getting following results:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<rss version="2.0"
 xmlns:blogChannel="http://backend.userland.com/blogChannelModule"
 xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#"
...

Comment: Ah, ok yes. I tried calling `Debug.Print s2` from within one of my Subs. I guess I can't do that? I do get the entire source code, which is great. But what I would like is to retrieve just that one number I referred to in the original post. Does that make sense? Thanks!

Comment: Changed the code as per your requirement let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks so much!!